# Is there a way you could pull from sharepoint using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded a macro that takes data from current document (excel) to another document (Excel) from a specific file folder.
Now the company is moving to share point. Is there a way to do that?

Now my VBA code is in an excel that:

1. Opening different -file path- excel file.
2. Copying and pasting data from one excel to other excel.

Can I access share point for the specific file path?

I have tried

‘’’ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address= “link” ‘’’

But this will not allow me to continue in the macro since it does not open the excel in the app. Rather it opens the direct internet url hyperlink.

Comment: You can open a workbook stored in SharePoint from Excel using `Workbooks.Open("http_path_here")`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access Sharepoint with a specific file path. If you sync the relevant Sharepoint folder, it will appear in your File Explorer and you can copy that file path to use in the VBA code.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b

Comment: It does take me to the online file. But it does not allow me to paste values into the excel file since it is online. It seems like it has to be open in app for macro to continue to paste in file

Comment: What is the line of VBA code and file path that you are running for this?